# Fibonacci grids

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory

We call a map $f:{\mathbb Z}\times {\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z}$ a *Fibonacci grid* if for all $x,y \in {\mathbb Z}$ we have that $f(x,y)$ is the sum of the neighboring values, that is, $$f(x,y) = f(x-1,y)+f(x+1,y) + f(x,y-1) + f(x,y+1).$$
Are there uncountably many Fibonacci grids?

Comment: Why call that Fibonacci? Suppose you have two rows given. When can the rows above and below be chosen consistent with your recurrence?

Comment: I could call them additive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

You may make two adjacent rows using any two strings of integers that you like:

> ...$\ 3\ \ 1\ \ \ 4\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 9\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 6\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 3\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 8\ $...
>
> ...$\ 2\ \ 7\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 4\ \ \ 5\ $...

Then fill in the rows above and below them one at a time; it's obvious that you can do this, and that you will fill it in with integers:

> ...$ \ \ {}^-13\ \ 1 \ {}^-16 \ \ \ etc.$
>
> ...$\ 3\ \ 1\ \ \ 4\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 9\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 6\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 3\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 8\ $...
>
> ...$\ 2\ \ 7\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 1\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 8\ \ \ 4\ \ \ 5\ $...
>
> ...$\ \ \ \ \, 3\, {}^-18\ \ 4\ \ \ \ etc. $

Comment: "Any integers you like" does not work, because even if the other rows are all zero, the condition is still a non-trivial equation $f(x,y)=f(x+1,y)+f(x-1,y)$. So you would have to use the Fibonacci numbers or something related for the non-zero row. And even then, the rows directly above and below it cannot be all zero. Your argument only shows that you can extend a $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$-grid to a full $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-grid.

Comment: The rows *below* it are all zero. You then fill in the rows above it recursively so as to satisfy your equation everywhere.

Comment: Yes and that does not work. In your example every single entry of the row directly below the non-zero one violates the condition.

Comment: The example is wrong as stated. However, it is true that if you fix two adjacent rows to arbitrary values, they can be uniquely extended to the whole grid to satisfy the equation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: You're right. I just realized this too and fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: I completely missed that -- thanks for pointing it out. (And the problem is fixed now.)

Comment: There is a context for all of this: in their work on algebraic dynamics, Kitchens, Lind and Schmidt studied systems of this type (where the values are in a compact group instead of Z). The canonical example is the Ledrappier 3-dot system.