# Injective additive grids

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

We call a map $f:{\mathbb Z}\times {\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z}$ an *[additive grid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292383/fibonacci-grids)* if for all $x,y \in {\mathbb Z}$ we have that $f(x,y)$ is the sum of the neighboring values, that is, $$f(x,y) = f(x-1,y)+f(x+1,y) + f(x,y-1) + f(x,y+1).$$
To me it feels like there cannot be injective additive grids - but I haven't been able to come up with a proof. So: are there injective additive grids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such a grid can be constructed easily by induction.
As can be seen from the [answer given to your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/292400/955), the adjacent rows can be chosen arbitrarily.
Denote the numbers in these rows by $\ldots,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,\ldots$ and $\ldots,y_{-1},y_0,y_1,\ldots$.
How does the rest of the grid change if we change $x_0$?
The elements that are in the infinite triangle whose sides are the halflines that go North-West and North-East from $x_0$.
The coefficients can be also computed, along the sides they are always $\pm x_0$, while inside the triangle some other numbers (possibly $0$).
Let us pick the numbers in the order $x_0,x_1,x_{-1},x_2,\ldots$ such that they grow very fast.
I claim that this guarantees that all elements of the grid are different.
(Let's ignore the $y_i$'s - it's easy to make the argument work for them too.)

Suppose that there are two numbers that are equal.
For both, take the most significant $x_i$ that influenced them.
This will be one that is diagonally South-West or South-East.
If these $x_i$ differ, the numbers also differ.
If they are the same, then the coefficient of how $x_i$ influences are numbers might be still different.
If it's also the same, take the second most significant $x_j$ etc.
Sooner or later we get a different $x_j$ or coefficient, and we are done.

Note that in the above argument we have used that for any $k$ there are finitely many numbers whose most significant $x_i$ has $|i|\le k$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, for example, what do you mean by "most significant" or by "the coefficient of how $x_i$ influences are numbers might be still different"

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I didn't write down all the details, but it would have been too long with properly defining everything.